# Simple url masking via htaccess doesn't work

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i'm trying to achieve the following:

I have domain.it and domain.fr

domain.it contains a website localized in multiple languages, so for example if you go to www.domain.it/fr/somecontent.php it shows that content in french language. This works. This website is hosted on a dedicated server.

In domain.fr i have an empty space with only an .htaccess. What i want is that when the user go to www.domain.fr/somecontent.php the browser shows the content from www.domain.it/fr/somecontent.php but keeping www.domain.fr/somecontent.php in the URL. So basically www.domain.fr/* should show the content from www.domain.it/fr/* but keeping www.domain.fr/* in the browser address bar.

Using an iframe is not an option because is not good for the SEO.

I'm using the following code inside the .htaccess on domain.fr (which is hosted on an OVH shared hosting):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.fr$
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://www.domain.it/fr/$1 [P]
```

But when i open www.domain.fr or www.domain.fr/somecontent.php in the browser it says "Forbidden: You don't have permission to access /somecontent.php on this server."

Instead, if i place [L] or [L,R=302] in place of the [P] in the last line of .htaccess, it correctly redirect to the www.domain.it/fr/somecontent.php showing it contents, but it shows the destination url (the it domain) in the browser bar.

So i think the rules are correct, but for some reason when i use the [P] flag which as far as i know is needed to mask the url, it doesn't work.

Have you any clues ?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you read up on the `P` flag in the documentation, specifically regarding what additional module provides this functionality, and then checked whether that module is available to you in the first place …?

Comment: If we're talking about different servers, I don't think you can accomplish that with a simple mod_rewrite rule. Instead, you possibly need a [reverse proxy](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/en/howto/reverse_proxy.html).

Comment: I'm seeing now that the apache error logs in the domain.fr hosting shows many errors like this:

[Mon Apr 16 01:23:29 2018] [error] [client xyz] [host www.domain.fr] [HandlerPolicyViolation] proxy-server is forbidden in this context ! (uri was '/assets/xyz.png')
[Mon Apr 16 03:29:19 2018] [error] [client xxxxx] [host domain.fr] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /homez.xyz/pronostiqa/www/.htaccess

So i suppose it is a problem with a module not installed/configured on the shared hosting ?

Comment: If i set domain.fr to use the same hosting as domain.it (same dedicated server) it should work with the [P] flag ?

Comment: UPDATE: i've pointed the domain.fr to the same hosting (dedicated server) where the site in domain.it is, then i've put the same .htaccess there. Now domain.fr and domain.it are two different virtualmin virtual servers in the same dedicated server.

What happen now is a different problem: if i go to https://domain.fr/ it shows a 404 error page from domain.it. With http instead of https it seems the htaccess directive doesn't works and it searches for the files inside domain.fr hosting...